# Помогите requests?

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests



rr = requests.get('https://api.myip.com').text
print(rr)
```

получаю словарь

```
{"ip":"66.249.75.9","country":"United States","cc":"US"}
```

как отдельно вывести значения?

пробовал .get но ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас строка type(rr): str

```
rr = requests.get('https://api.myip.com').json()
print(rr)
print(type(rr))
```

переменная rr словарь

```
print(rr.get('country'))

United States
```

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите, что значит "вывести отдельно"?
Если Вы хотите вывести их в консоль, можете попробовать:

```
for key, value in rr.items():
    print(f"{key} = {value}")
```

Comment: в коде переменная rr текст, а не словарь :)

Comment: спасибо я уже понял как вывести через json и предполагал что ошибка в том что это текст